# Failed test with mock files using JUnit4 TemporaryFolder

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Im starting with mock in my unit tests. Wanted to upgrade method to using files.
Mocks with some strings or numbers work, but now code has failed test.
I have class with method:

```
public class FileService {
    public List<File> findFilesUsingSuffix(File root, String suffix) {
        List<File> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (root.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = root.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    list.addAll(findFilesUsingSuffix(file, suffix));
                }
            }
        } else if (root.getName().endsWith(suffix)) {
            list.add(root);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

and test:

```
public class FileServiceTest {
    private FileService fileService;
    private TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder;
 
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        fileService = mock(FileService.class);
 
        temporaryFolder = mock(TemporaryFolder.class);
        File file1 = temporaryFolder.newFile("file.java");
        File file2 = temporaryFolder.newFile("file.swf");
        File file3 = temporaryFolder.newFile("file2.java");
        File file4 = temporaryFolder.newFile("picture.jpg");
        File file5 = temporaryFolder.newFile("photo.jpg");
        File file6 = temporaryFolder.newFile("movie.mp4");
        File file7 = temporaryFolder.newFile("music.mp3");
        File file8 = temporaryFolder.newFile("someFile.java");
        File file9 = temporaryFolder.newFile("someDoc.doc");
        File file10 = temporaryFolder.newFile("excelThing.xls");
        File file11 = temporaryFolder.newFolder("java");
    }
 
    @Test
    public void findFilesUsingSuffixIsTrue() throws IOException {
        //given
        List<File> expectedList = List.of(
                new File("file.java"), new File("file2.java"), new File("someFile.java")
        );
 
        when(fileService.findFilesUsingSuffix(ArgumentMatchers.any(File.class),any(String.class))).thenCallRealMethod();
 
        //when
        List<File> result = fileService.findFilesUsingSuffix(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), ".java");
 
        //then
        assertEquals(expectedList, result);
    }
}
```

I'm getting empty list in result, but idk what i did incorrectly

Comment: What is the `TemporaryFolder` class ans why are you mocking that class?

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/junit/junit-creating-temporary-filefolder-using-temporaryfolder-rule/         i was using this

Comment: You are misusing `TemporaryFolder`. You call unstubbed methods on a mock - they are completely ignored. Make up your mind: either use TemporaryFolder and real files or use mocks. Mocking a class that isnt used by method under test makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your procedure of mocking.

- You don't need to `mock(TemporaryFolder.class)` as that class is provided by JUnit4, which requires to provide folder/file names.
- There is no need to `mock(FileService.class)`, which actually needs to be tested.
- Get the TemporaryFolder as a Rule

i.e.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
```

Here is a working code which matches the test and passes:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;

public class FileServiceTest {
  private FileService fileService;

  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    fileService = new FileService();

    File file1 = temporaryFolder.newFile("file.java");
    File file2 = temporaryFolder.newFile("file.swf");
    File file3 = temporaryFolder.newFile("file2.java");
    File file4 = temporaryFolder.newFile("picture.jpg");
    File file5 = temporaryFolder.newFile("photo.jpg");
    File file6 = temporaryFolder.newFile("movie.mp4");
    File file7 = temporaryFolder.newFile("music.mp3");
    File file8 = temporaryFolder.newFile("someFile.java");
    File file9 = temporaryFolder.newFile("someDoc.doc");
    File file10 = temporaryFolder.newFile("excelThing.xls");
    File file11 = temporaryFolder.newFolder("java");
  }

  @Test
  public void findFilesUsingSuffixIsTrue() throws IOException {
    //given
    List<String> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    expectedList.add("someFile.java");
    expectedList.add("file2.java");
    expectedList.add("file.java");

    //when
    List<File> result = fileService.findFilesUsingSuffix(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), ".java");

    List<String> allFileNames = result.stream().map(File::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //then
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedList, allFileNames);
  }
}
```